# Function works for small samples but not larger ones (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, function, memory-management, nlp

I'm trying to make a function to see if words appear within a certain distance of one another, my code is as follows:

```
file_cont = [['man', 'once', 'upon', 'time', 'love', 
'princess'], ['python', 'code', 'cool', 'uses', 'java'],
['man', 'help', 'test', 'weird', 'love']] #words I want to measure 'distance' between

dat = [{ind: val for val, ind in enumerate(el)} for el in file_cont]

def myfunc(w1, w2, dist, dat):
    arr = []
    for x in dat:
        i1 = x.get(w1)
        i2 = x.get(w2)
        if (i1 is not None) and (i2 is not None) and (i2 - i1 <= dist ):    
            arr.append(list(x.keys())[i1:i2+1])
    return arr
```

It works in this instance,

*myfunc("man", "love",4, dat)* returns *[['man', 'once', 'upon', 'time', 'love'],
['man', 'help', 'test', 'weird', 'love']]* which is what I want

The problem I have is when I use a much bigger dataset (the elements of file_cont becomes thousands of words), it outputs odd results

For example I know the words 'jon' and 'snow' appear together in at least one instance in one of the elements of file_cont

When I do *myfunc('jon','snow',6,dat)* I get:

*[[], [], ['castle', 'ward'], [], [], []]*

something completely out of context, it doesn't mention 'jon' or 'snow'

What is the problem here and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Two things come to my mind: first, you mention that the problem only occurs when using a bigger dataset. How are you using this dataset? Are you reading a text file and splitting it into a list? The problem could be caused by how you read your data.

Otherwise, you mention the case of ```"jon"``` and ```"snow"```. Perhaps should you make sure you search through words in a case insensitive way, for instance using ```s.lower()``` where ```s``` is a string?

Comment: @bglbrt I have lowercased the words and still have the same issue

Comment: @bglbrt it is also the same data fromat [['string1', 'string2'], ['string3', 'string4', 'string5']] just longer

Comment: I added an answer investigating further the problem, which I believe comes from the fact that your new data may have multiple occurrences of the same words.

Comment: @bglbrt the code works for longer large lists but still doesn't seem to work for a list of long lists i.e [ [ 'word1',....., 'word1000'] , [ 'word3', ...... 'word5000'], ['word4', .... 'word400']] even when the words I want to find the distance between are in the same list (which is what I'm aiming for)

Comment: I added an example with a list of lists at the end of my answer. If this still doesn't work, I think it will be hard to solve your issue without examples of where it fails...

Comment: @bglbrt the example I am using I have put on https://pastebin.com/NyPGiXMq , try and pick any two words next to one another and call the function because it doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: This is confusing because, defining a list taking the name ```data``` containing exactly your given input, and running (for instance) ```new_func(w1='Michael', w2='Jackson', dist=3, data[0])``` (where we use ```data[0]``` to evaluate for the first list in the list of lists) yields your desired output...

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that your text may contain multiple occurrences of the same word, which you typically observe with larger excerpts.

Here's a minimal working example showing how the function may fail:

```
new_file = [['man', 'once', 'man', 'time', 'love', 'once']]
data = [{ind: val for val, ind in enumerate(el)} for el in new_file]

def myfunc(w1, w2, dist, dat):
    arr = []
    for x in dat:
        i1 = x.get(w1)
        i2 = x.get(w2)
        if (i1 is not None) and (i2 is not None) and (i2 - i1 <= dist ):    
            arr.append(list(x.keys())[i1:i2+1])
    return arr

myfunc("man", "love", 4, data)
# > [['time', 'love']]
```

Notice that here, your dictionary will look like this:

```
# > [{'man': 2, 'once': 5, 'time': 3, 'love': 4}]
```

This is because, when creating the dictionary, each new occurence of a word will replace its key in the dictionary with the newly observed (higher) index. Thus, the function `myfunc` fails as the keys in the dictionary do not correspond anymore to the indices of the words in the excerpt.

---

A way to achieve what you want to do could be (for instance):

```
data = ['man', 'once', 'upon', 'man', 'time', 'love', 'princess', 'man']
w1 = 'man'
w2 = 'love'
dist = 3

def new_func(w1, w2, dist, data):

    w1_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data) if x == w1]
    w2_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data) if x == w2]

    for i in w1_indices:
        for j in w2_indices:
            if abs(i-j) < dist:
                print(data[min(i, j):max(i, j)+1])
                
new_func(w1, w2, dist, data)
# > ['man', 'time', 'love']
# > ['love', 'princess', 'man']
```

With a list of lists like in your case, you can do:

```
file_cont = [['man', 'once', 'upon', 'time', 'love', 'princess'], ['python', 'code', 'cool', 'uses', 'java'],
['man', 'help', 'test', 'weird', 'love']]

results = [new_func(w1, w2, dist, x) for x in file_cont]
print(results)
# > ['man', 'once', 'upon', 'time', 'love']
# > ['man', 'help', 'test', 'weird', 'love']
```

Comment: I believe your code has an error on :  print(a[min(i, j):max(i, j)+1]), should this a be abs?

Comment: You're right - I corrected it, it should be ```print(data[min(i, j):max(i, j)+1])```.